# SQL query performance improvement for advice

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-variables

Post the problem statement and current code I am using, and wondering if any smart ideas to improve query performance? Using MySQL. Thanks.

Write a SQL query to rank scores. If there is a tie between two scores, both should have the same ranking. Note that after a tie, the next ranking number should be the next consecutive integer value. In other words, there should be no "holes" between ranks.

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Score |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 3.50  |
| 2  | 3.65  |
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.85  |
| 5  | 4.00  |
| 6  | 3.65  |
+----+-------+
```

For example, given the above Scores table, your query should generate the following report (order by highest score):

```
+-------+------+
| Score | Rank |
+-------+------+
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 3.85  | 2    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.50  | 4    |
+-------+------+

SELECT 
    s.score, scores_and_ranks.rank
FROM
    Scores s
JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        score_primary.score, COUNT(DISTINCT score_higher.score) + 1 AS rank
    FROM
        Scores score_primary
    LEFT JOIN Scores score_higher 
    ON score_higher.score > score_primary.score
    GROUP BY score_primary.score
) scores_and_ranks 
ON s.score = scores_and_ranks.score
ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

BTW, post issue from Gordon's code.

[image]

BTW, tried sgeddes's code, but met with new issues,

[image]

New issue from Gordon's code,

[image]

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: unfortunately `Mysql` does not support `Dense Rank`

Comment: Check here http://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/grouped-dense-rank-function-mysql-sql-query.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User defined variables are probably faster than what you are doing.  However, you need to be careful when using them.  In particular, you cannot assign a variable in one expression and use it in another -- I mean, you *can*, but the expressions can be evaluated in any order so your code may not do what you intend.

So, you need to do all the work in a single expression:

```
select s.*,
       (@rn := if(@s = score, @rn,
                  if(@s := score, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                 )
       ) as rank
from scores s cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @s := 0) params
order by score desc;
```

Comment: Hi Gorden, thanks for the input. I tried to test your code but met with issues, and I am using an online testing system here => leetcode.com/problems/rank-scores, and I post the error message in my original post. Your advice is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: @linMa . . . The error message makes no sense.  There is no `s` in my query that could be interpreted as a column (as a table alias, yes, but not as a column).

Comment: Thanks Gorden, actually the table name is Scores, other than scores, and I changed the first character to uppercase, and then it got the error. If you have any thoughts, appreciate for sharing. :)

Comment: And actually s in your statement should be an alias of the table, but I am not sure why after I change scores to Scores, s is recognized as a column?

Comment: Maybe because of this statement, "@s = s", s is treated as a column? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa . . . The answer no longer has `@s = s`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it seem your code has new issues, I post the error message I got in my original post. Your advice is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: @LinMa . . . I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Gordon, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `user-defined variables`:

```
select score, 
       @rnk:=if(@prevScore=score,@rnk,@rnk+1) rnk,
       @prevScore:=score
from scores
     join (select @rnk:=0, @prevScore:=0) t
order by score desc
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85a65e/1)

Comment: Thanks sgeddes, curious why used defined variable is faster? Is it generally faster? Or faster just in my specific or similar cases? Appreciate if you could deep dive a bit more why in my case user defined variable is faster?

Comment: Hi sgeddes, thanks for the input. I tried to test your code but met with issues, and I am using an online testing system here => leetcode.com/problems/rank-scores, and I post the error message in my original post. Your advice is highly appreciated. :)