# Building a live database (approach)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mongodb, database

I just want a approach on how to build a database with live records, so don't just downvote. I don't expect any code.

At the moment I have a MySql database with about 2 thousand users, they are are getting more though. Each player/user has several points, which are increasing or decreasing by certain actions.

My goal is that this database gets refreshed about every second and the user with more points move up and others move down... and so on

My question is, what is the best approach for this "live database" where records have to be updated every second. In MySql I can run time based actions which are executing a SQL command but this isn't the greatest way I think. Can someone suggest a good way to handle this? E.g. other Database providers like MongoDB or anything else?

**EDIT**

This doesn't work client side, so I can't simply push/post it into the databse due some time based events. For explanation: A user is training his character in the application. This training (to get 1 level up) takes 12 hours. After the time is elapsed the record should be updated in the database AUTOMATICALLY also if the user doesn't send a post request by his self (if the user is not logged in) other users should see the updated data in his profile.

Comment: If a action of a player occurs then store it in your table. To get a live view of your data run a specifc query every time you want to refresh your GUI

Comment: No this isn't that easy because certain tasks need about 1 or more days to complete. I can only push/post them to the server if the user logs in and it might be that an event takes 1 day but he logs in after 1 week and in this time there is no update of the record. @juergend

Comment: You can use jquery ajax for this purpose

Comment: Can you give an example of an event, that takes more time (like days)?

Comment: The database that contains the data is always updated. I think the point is getting the data so it changes realtime for everyone that is viewing the data. If points are given to a user in a spread way (like 1000 points, spread over 3 days) you can store date/times and calculate the current amount of points at every time you want. If a user has a process 1.5 days done, you can calculate it has 500 points, without updating the database every second.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept the fact that rankings will be stale to some extent. Your predicament is no different than any other gaming platform (or SO rankings for that matter). Business decisions were put in place and constantly get reviewed for the level of staleness. Take the leaderboards on tags here, for instance. Or the recent change that has profile pages updated a lot more frequently, versus around 4AM GMT.

Consider the use of MySQL Events. It is built-in functionality that replaces the need for cron tasks. I have 3 event-related links off my profile page if interested. You could calculate ranks on a timed schedule (your tolerance for staleness) and the users' requests for them would be fast (faster than the below from Gordon). On the con-side, they are stale.

Consider not saving (writing) rank info but rather focus just on filling in the slots of your other data. And get your rankings on the fly. As an example, see this rankings answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34169806) from Gordon. It is dynamic, runs upon request with at least at that moment non-staleness, and would not require Events.

Know that only you should decide what is tolerable for the UX.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. So you would suggest to me using events in MySQL? Like calculating the rankings every 10 seconds or something like that? Is it possible to calculate thousands of records with that or is this very slow? If yes is there a different solution?